# Shutdown not working for Users logged in through winbind

Tags: gnome, samba, shutdown, policykit

I have a Samba server acting as AD/DC and a client authenticating against it.

Domain Users can log in and out just fine, shutdown and restart does not work.
For Local Users shutdown and restart works.

If I click shutdown, the "shutdown or restart" window opens, clicking on either one does not do anything. The moment I move out of one of the 2 buttons, the window closes without any message.

To set up my Client I followed [this wiki](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Samba_Winbind) mostly.

Answer (score 2):

Changed `/usr/share/polkit-1/action/org.freedesktop.login1.policy`

under `action org.freedesktop.login1.power-off`

change `allow any` to `yes`